# Cron to restart ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron, restart

Is it possible to restart a ubuntu machine when it has not enough space?

Facts: 
 I have created a vagrant machine that is used as a jenkins slave.
 This machine uses /tmp as a workspace.
 From time to time this gets filled and I just want to make the machine restart automatically. Or clean /tmp.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: You could write a bash script which cron runs each morning around 4am (or whenever), and deletes each file (entire directories) as you wish.

Comment: It is possible you need to read this: http://blog.rimuhosting.com/2012/02/20/cron-script-for-checking-disk-space/ then you just need to add restart command in cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I did was to add in bashrc a script that cleans up /tmp and installed thiss plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Post+Script+Plugin

After every job I just ssh to the slave machine, bashrc will do the rest